# Move a unique_ptr with custom deleter to a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, c++14, unique-ptr

I have a function which creates a unique_ptr with a custom deleter and returns it:

```
auto give_unique_ptr() {
    auto deleter = [](int* pi) {
        delete pi;
    };
    int* i = new int{1234};
    return std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(deleter)>(i, deleter);
}
```

In the client code of that function, I'd like to move the `unique_ptr` into a `shared_ptr`, but I don't know how to do that given that I don't know the decltype of my custom deleter outside of the function.

I guess it should look something like this:

```
auto uniquePtr = give_unique_ptr();
auto sharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<..??..>(std::move(uniquePtr));
```

What do I have to write instead of *..??..* to get the correct type?

If this is possible, will the `shared_ptr` behave nicely and call my custom deleter created inside the `give_unique_ptr()` function when it's usage count reaches zero?

Comment: Remember that `shared_ptr` *erases* the deleter. The only template parameter is the type pointed-to in the current view.

Comment: @o11c what does that mean? I tried the proposed solution by @Nawaz and the deleter gets called after the `shared_ptr` is destroyed.

Comment: it means that the deleter's type is not related to the `shared_ptr`'s type. You can even cast to, say, a `shared_ptr<char>` and it will still call the original deleter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you know (or want to explicitly type) the *type* of the object, then you can do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sharedPtr(std::move(uniquePtr));
```

The constructor of `std::shared_ptr` will take care of the deletor.

---

If you, however, want the *type* to be inferred, then:

```
auto sharedPtr = make_shared_from(std::move(uniquePtr));
```

where `make_shared_from` is:

```
template<typename T, typename D>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared_from(std::unique_ptr<T,D> && p)
{
   //D is deduced but it is of no use here!
   //We need only `T` here, the rest will be taken 
   //care by the constructor of shared_ptr
   return std::shared_ptr<T>(std::move(p));
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: IMO, it would probably be better to have `make_shared_from` take an rvalue reference to make it outwardly visible that it was being moved from

Comment: @RyanHaining or even a value, that's more C++11-idiomatic in most cases.

Comment: @RyanHaining: That is also good. How about `move_from` instead of `make_shared_from`?

Comment: @o11c I can't say I agree, would there be any difference other than incurring an additional move?

Comment: @RyanHaining Passing by value means less indirections, and the additional move is negligible since it's trivial and only 2 words. Of course this is all moot if the compiler inlines enough ...

Comment: @o11c what do you mean by "less indirections"?

Comment: @o11c: Frankly, I don't see any benefit of "pass by value" here.

Comment: @RyanHaining To load from an `int *` argument, only a single memory access must be made. To load from an `int **` or `int *&` argument, *two* memory access must be made serially. Though now that I think about it, non-POD types add the pointer automatically even by-value, but I still do it for consistency and obviousness.

Comment: @o11c the `shared_ptr` constructor takes a `unique_ptr&&`, so it's hard to call it more "idiomatic" to take a value.  Custom deleters can be larger to the point where an additional move may not be as negligible as you think.  passing.  Moving a pointer is trivial, moving a `unique_ptr` is not.

Comment: @o11c your last comment is incorrect, unless you mean dereferencing through two layers of pointers, which wouldn't happen here anyway since nowhere does it actually access the owned resource.

Comment: `&&` for sink arguments make sense and is idiomatic, even if you have a sink-only type.  With an inlined function, all this register/pointer-counting is not going to matter, anyhow.  And @Ryan's point about "we don't know how much custom deleters cost" is a good one.  I'd choose `std::shared_ptr<T> share_unique_ptr( std::unique_ptr<T,D>&& ptr )` myself as the name/signature: the the fact this returns a shared ptr should be part of the function name.

Comment: @Nawaz I'd maintain that having the function take an rvalue reference is the right choice for outward clarity.  Having another "move" function is less than desirable imo.

Comment: Alright guys, `make_shared_from` with rvalue-ref as parameter has been finalized, and edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

```
auto uniquePtr = give_unique_ptr();
auto sharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<decltype(uniquePtr)::element_type>(std::move(uniquePtr));
```

And yes, the `shared_ptr` will store - and later use - the custom deleter.